# Pandas merge two data frame with different length

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes with different length, one about population and the other about death. I need to merge them. This is the structure of the population table...

```
Year     Age      Female         Male        Total
1933       0     984472.26   1015361.55   1999833.81
1933       1    1040496.02   1064088.29   2104584.31
1933       2    1093043.81   1117527.14   2210570.95
1933       3    1107994.31   1135046.59   2243040.90
1933       4    1130624.43   1179513.62   2310138.05
1933       5    1168930.56   1228225.14   2397155.70
1933       6    1190706.56   1238800.33   2429506.89
1933       7    1203816.58   1245575.51   2449392.09
1933       8    1224285.20   1255721.28   2480006.48
1933       9    1230968.73   1254639.67   2485608.40
1933      10    1243608.10   1262739.94   2506348.04
```

The structure of the death table is the same as population but with different values. If you notice the age increments by each row. The population table has more rows than death table. After merging the two tables I'm expecting to have `NaN's` in the death rows. However, after running the code to merge the tables I'm getting the following output...

```
  year,p_age,p_female,p_male,p_total,d_age,d_female,d_male,d_total
0,1933,0,984472.26,1015361.55,1999833.81,0,52615.77,68438.11,121053.88
1,1933,0,984472.26,1015361.55,1999833.81,1,8917.13,10329.16,19246.29
2,1933,0,984472.26,1015361.55,1999833.81,2,4336.92,5140.05,9476.97
3,1933,0,984472.26,1015361.55,1999833.81,3,3161.59,3759.88,6921.47
4,1933,0,984472.26,1015361.55,1999833.81,4,2493.84,2932.59,5426.43
5,1933,0,984472.26,1015361.55,1999833.81,5,2139.87,2537.53,4677.4
6,1933,0,984472.26,1015361.55,1999833.81,6,1939.7,2337.76,4277.46
7,1933,0,984472.26,1015361.55,1999833.81,7,1760.47,2163.9,3924.37
8,1933,0,984472.26,1015361.55,1999833.81,8,1602.2,2015.97,3618.17
9,1933,0,984472.26,1015361.55,1999833.81,9,1464.88,1893.96,3358.84
10,1933,0,984472.26,1015361.55,1999833.81,10,1357.91,1805.52,3163.43
```

If you notice the age is getting repeat and the dataframe grew from 9 thousand plus to 1 million. This is the merge code I'm utilizing...

```
df_usa = usa_population.merge(usa_death, how='left', on='year')
```

I have also used...

```
df_usa = pd.merge(usa_population, usa_death, how='left', on='year')
```

or...

```
df_usa = pd.merge(usa_population, usa_death, how='inner', on='year')
```

How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to merge on the `age` column as well. Try this:

```
df_usa = usa_population.merge(usa_death, how='left', on=['year','age'])
```